# Android Studio can't detect Samsung S5

Tags: android, ddms

I have a SAMSUNG S5 and i'm starting to learn how to program in Android.  At first Android Studio detected my device and I was able to test my programs fine but all of a sudden it can't find it anymore.  Everytime time I go to 'reset adb' in Android Device Monitor it always gives me this error:

```
Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

My computer detects my device but Android Studio does not.

I've tried restarting Android studio and my entire computer.

I've tried different USB ports and USBs.

I've also tried uninstalling and re installing the driver.

Nothing works, please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out - for some reason my phone shuts off USB Debugging for no reason.  I still sometimes get this issue after I've turned it on and I look at my phone and its off again.  Really weird but that was the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Also, try changing usb computer connection type (found in notifications bar). For me, connecting as a camera (ptp as opposed to the default mtp) was the solution.

Comment: I figured it out.  Apparently my phone turns off USB debugging periodically for no reason at all.

Comment: Excellent - glad it helped :)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have downloaded the latest version of the googleusb driver from your SDK manager. If that doesnt help try a Samsung universal ADB driver :

http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi

And of course dont forget to enable USB debugging on your device

Comment: http://www.androidpit.com/enable-usb-debugging-on-samsung-galaxy-s5 to enable debug mode

Comment: Google USB Driver --> That only pertains to Windows Computers so if you are working from a MAC -- this wouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You must check these first:

1- Install Google USB Driver --> open SDK Manager and then download and install it

[image]

2- Enable USB Debuging mode in your phone--> in Settings--> Developer options

I ended up downloading Samsung USB driver from here: 
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads

You have to choose your device and then you can download and install the software.Then restart adb:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

You can see your device added into devices in adb by running this command:

```
adb devices
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers didn't work for me.

I had to follow these instructions to enable developer builds to the device:

> 1. Go to the menu
> 2. Launch Settings
> 3. Access the “About Device” menu
> 4. Go down to “Build Number”
> 5. **Then tap on the build number 7 times**
> 6. After the 7th tap you will be told that you are now a developer
> 7. Now when you go back to the settings menu, the developer options will now be enabled and you can do whatever you want in there.
> 8. Now to enable USB debugging you will need to open Developer options and tick the box that says USB debugging.

via https://www.androidpit.com/enable-usb-debugging-on-samsung-galaxy-s5

Thanks to John, who posted the link in this comment: [Android Studio can't detect Samsung S5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592961/android-studio-cant-detect-samsung-s5#comment45831697_27593178)